# Show hide class on hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, hover

I am relatively new to jQuery, and I would like to be able to show a menu on mouseover.

Here is the HTML content:

```
<td class ="comment_div"> <?php echo("$comment_data['comment']); ?> <br/>
    <span class="comment_actions"> Approve | Delete | Spam | Edit</span>
</td>
```

Then the jQuery code:

```
$("comment_div").hover(
    function() { $(".comment_actions").show(); },
    function() { $(".comment_actions").hide(); }
);
```

This works except for I'm pulling multiple comments out and this only will show the menu on the first div no matter what "comment" is hovered. I would like to have the menu show only for the comment that is currently being hovered over. I think I need to use "$this" to make this work, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I'm reading that correctly, the format should be-

```
$(".comment_div").hover(
  function() { $(this).children(".comment_actions").show(); },
  function() { $(this).children(".comment_actions").hide(); }
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that show/hide "comment_div"? I am trying to show/hide "comment_actions" on hover.

Comment: You are absolutely right- I am half asleep today and out of practice. That *should* be fixed now.

Comment: Wonderful!- Sorry again for the missteps there.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for me:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".container").hover(
            function() { $(this).children('.comment_actions').show(); },
            function() { $(this).children('.comment_actions').hide(); }
        );
    });

</script>

<style>
</style>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class ="container"><br/>
            asd<span class="comment_actions">Approve | Delete</span>
        </td>
        <td class ="container"><br/>
            asd <span class="comment_actions">Approve | Delete</span>
        </td>
        <td class ="container"><br/>
            asd<span class="comment_actions"> Approve| Delete</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, the issue you'll face is hover actions over a div that has `display: none; set`. You might want to consider wrapping it in something that's mouse sensitive, and then displaying/hiding children instead.