# Displaying contents details via hover like stackoverflow with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Show hide class on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449574/jquery-show-hide-class-on-hover)

just like stackoverflow, when you hover on any tag it will load the description and details of that tag. Is there a way i can accomplish this with a javascript plugin like jquery of doing in manually. Any reference would be grate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) is a good jQuery plugin which provides tooltips with inline and AJAX definitions. For example an AJAX definition can be achieved with this HTML:

```
<a class="definition" href="link-to-tag.html" rel="ajax.html">tag</a>
```

And load the jQuery plugin with the following Javascript:

```
$('a.definition').cluetip();
```

Comment: in clutip is there a way i can put a loading image to indicate that the request is loading

Comment: this is very cool cant wait to start using it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery there are many plugins and scripts to acheive a similar tooltip effect. One that appears to be quite good can be found [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

Comment: i want to load the contents via ajax.

Comment: There is no reason you can't load the contents via AJAX... have a look at this page: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html. You can load content via AJAX into the `<div class="tooltip">` when the page loads (or any time you like).

Comment: its cool but not as i expected. On stackoverflow it happens when you hover on the tag and you see a loading bar trying to fetch the contents from the database that's what i am talking about. it should try a load the contents first. this is to prevent so many sql queries when the page loads. I need that type in order to prevent so many sql queries

Comment: Well it looks like clueTip from your accepted answer is the one for you then!

Comment: ok thanks. just wanted to have the best possible approach to it

Answer (score 0):

http://www.shahin.co.nr/16-cool-jquery-tooltip-plugins/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/